# Problem with Duplicate Meta / tag description in Webmaster Tool

Tags: plugins, seo, customization

Hope you are fine and in a good health.

I owned a blog www.ismag.com and today when I check my website in Google webmaster tool I found these errors in html improvement.

[image]

I am using WordPress SEO by Yoast. Please help me to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Your case is not about the yoast plugin. You have duplicate on a lot of pages, with 2 slashes in the end.
It seems the cause for this is your "share box" plugin or something like that, the one who gives the options for sharing/comments on the thumbnails, and more specifically - the comment one. Check for example http://www.ismag.com/category/technology/tech-news/, on the hover of any of the thumbnails, the comments lead to the wrong doubleslashed version.
The fix should be easy, most probably there is slash in the plugin file referencing the comment button itself. I just have no idea which plugin is this, but anyway - this is your problem.

Comment: Hello... this is the answer from theme developer : http://prntscr.com/7af90n

Link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7780859/htaccess-rewrite-to-force-trailing-slash-at-the-end

Comment: I have found this function in my function.php file.

// Prevents double posts on second page

add_filter('redirect_canonical','pif_disable_redirect_canonical');

function pif_disable_redirect_canonical($redirect_url) {
    if (is_singular()) $redirect_url = false;
return $redirect_url;
}

When I remove this function the problem of trailing slash disappears. Can you please tell me what originally this function is doing ?

Answer (score 0):

Ensure these are enabled (See images)

[image] [image]